# Could not find a part of the path C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, filestream, system.io.file

My application in winforms c# and my form need to retrieve the image from database and store in the local machine (Where my application is installed) and viewed in the PictureBox control.

I have the following code (To store image locally and to view in  PictureBox control):

```
//dsProjects is a dataset which is retrieved from database
if (dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
     int idxCurPageJob = (iPageNum * 8);

     string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
     string folder = "TEMP"; 

     string fullpath = string.Empty;

     fullpath = Path.Combine(path, folder);

     bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(fullpath);
     try
     {
          if (!exists)
              Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
          else
          {
              Directory.Delete(fullpath, true);
              Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
          }
     }
     catch (Exception) 
     {}

     try
     {
         if (dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count > idxCurPageJob)
         {
             pnl1.Visible = true;
             pnl1.AccessibleName = dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows[idxCurPageJob][1].ToString();
             Labelfld1.Text = dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows[idxCurPageJob][0].ToString();

             byte[] bgImg = (byte[])dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows[idxCurPageJob][2];
             string proCode = dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows[idxCurPageJob][3].ToString();

             string strfn = Path.Combine(fullpath, proCode + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()) + idxCurPageJob);

             using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@strfn, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
             {
                 fs.Write(bgImg, 0, bgImg.Length);
                 fs.Flush();
                 fs.Close();
             }

             picBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(strfn);
             picBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
             picBox1.Refresh();
         }
         if (dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count > (idxCurPageJob + 1))
         {
             pnl2.Visible = true;
             Labelfld2.Text = dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows[idxCurPageJob + 1][0].ToString();

             pnl2.AccessibleName = dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows[idxCurPageJob + 1][1].ToString();
             byte[] bgImg = (byte[])dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows[idxCurPageJob + 1][2];
             string proCode = dsProjects.Tables[0].Rows[idxCurPageJob + 1][3].ToString();

             string strfn = Path.Combine(fullpath, proCode + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()) + (idxCurPageJob + 1));

             using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@strfn, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
             {
                 fs.Write(bgImg, 0, bgImg.Length);
                 fs.Flush();
                 fs.Close();
             }

             picBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(strfn);
             picBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
             picBox2.Refresh();
         }
         .....

     }
     catch (Exception ex) 
     {
         StreamWriter sw;
         DateTime dtLogFileCreated = DateTime.Now;

         try
         {
             sw = new StreamWriter("Project Form crash-" + dtLogFileCreated.Day + dtLogFileCreated.Month + dtLogFileCreated.Year + "-" + dtLogFileCreated.Second + dtLogFileCreated.Minute + dtLogFileCreated.Hour + ".txt");

            sw.WriteLine("### Server Crash ###");
            sw.WriteLine("### Message  : ###" + ex.Message + "### StackTrace : ###" + ex.StackTrace + "###Soruce : ###" + ex.Source + "### InnerException : ###" + ex.InnerException + "### Data : ###" + ex.Data + " ### END of LOG ###");
            sw.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Afer installing the application in PC and when restarting the PC and trying to open the application then to this form the application get crashed. But after restart the application (Not the PC) I am not facing any issue.

Below is the Error Log details.

```
 ### Server Crash :###  
### Message  : ###Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Autoscan Pte Ltd\STK PTA\TEMP\1100101308609520058907460'.  
### StackTrace : ###   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)  
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)  
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at PTA.Forms.frmPIProject.SetCurrentPageProjects()###Soruce : ###mscorlib### InnerException : 
###### Data : ###System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal 
### END of LOG ###
```

This error is happening in this line of code

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@strfn, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs.Write(bgImg, 0, bgImg.Length);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Really appreciate your help on this

Comment: Can you debug and tell what value is held by `@strfn`? Most probably the file cannot be opened because it 1. Isn´t there (wrong path) or 2. You don´t have permission to open it.

Comment: The folder has the word TEMP in it - is it being deleted by something when the PC is restarted?

Comment: @Marcus The value in strfn is "C:\Program Files\Autoscan\STKPTA\TEMP\1100101308617311119720900" The Temp folder is created where my application is installed. The path is correct. When I am restarting my application I am not facing this issue. Thanks

Comment: @LeeWillis Even the TEMP folder is deleted it should be created again as per my code.

Comment: Why would you want to put it there, though? Just use the Windows temp folder using `Path.GetTempPath()`. In fact, why write it to disk at all? You should be able to make a Bitmap object straight from the bytes and open that.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your directory does not get created.. It's best to not swallow your exceptions. Remove the try / catch from this piece of code and check if the error is here:

```
if (!exists)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
else
{
    Directory.Delete(fullpath, true);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
}
```

I think your app does not have the right permissions to write in the Program Files folder.

Comment: Since the application runs under the administrator login it can able to create and write in the Program Files folder. If we remove try / catch block sometimes if the directory cannot be deleted because it's used by another process, will get an exception

Comment: Creating temp files in a folder under program files is still really, really bad practice, though.

Comment: I have a few programs that create and delete folders, and we had to put it in a loop and exit when the folder was created/deleted, as we would run into issues with the file system lagging behind the application.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the fact you call it a "temp" folder, and the fact you never even bother to keep track of the names of the files you create, I kind of doubt you actually have any reason to save the image to disk.

You can just make an Image object straight from the bytes, and assign it to your control:

```
byte[] bgImg = ???; // your code to fetch the bytes from the DB
Image imgFromDb;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bgImg))
using (Image tmpImg = Image.FromStream(ms))
{
    // Needs to be wrapped in "new Bitmap(Image img)" constructor to avoid
    // the image being linked to and depending on the input stream.
    imgFromDb = new Bitmap(tmpImg);
}
picBox1.Image = imgFromDb;
```

Comment: The problem is not with the  "temp" folder. Even If I change the folder name to "FILES" or "Images" for the first time whenever my pc restarted, my application get crashed when I access this form. For Images , I have used image object straight form the bytes & assigned to the control. But in the another form I need to convert bytes to **pdf** file and need to view the file in my form. Again I am creating folder in BaseDirectory and downloading the file.

Comment: `using (FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                                {
                                    objfilestream.Write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.Length);
                                    objfilestream.Close();
                                }` This piece of code is throwing an same exception. Kindly assist

Comment: By removing this piece of code my application is working fine `fullpath = Path.Combine(path, folder);

     bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(fullpath);
     try
     {
          if (!exists)
              Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
          else
          {
              Directory.Delete(fullpath, true);
              Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
          }
     }
     catch (Exception) 
     {}` I also replace string variable as `string fullpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` Any idea Why  `Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)` throws an exception?

Comment: Seriously. Start by using the Windows temp folder as you're supposed to, first, and _then_ maybe you can go on and see if you still get problems -_-

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any changes make sure you have given full permission to the folder and files.

I resolved this issue by turning off one of the settings in my browser. You can disable one of the settings in security tab > custom level > "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" in IE and then try again.

This settings gets enabled when you add your site to the trusted sites. Either remove your site from trusted list or manually disable this setting and issue will be fixed.

Similarly if you are facing the same issue on other browsers, look for the above setting and mark it as disable and issue will get resolved.